# Get the number of parent objects in a json object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following is the JSON array, I want to get number of parent objects and then run for loop on them to get each object value.

It should give total count 2 as I have two parent objects - canvas0 and canvas1.

```
{"canvas0":
     "{"objects":      
 [{"type":"textbox","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":40,"top":350,"width":200,"height":20.97,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":"ADDRESScanvasPage1","fontSize":16,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.16,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"center","textBackgroundColor":"","styles":{},"minWidth":20}],"background":""}"


,"canvas1":"{"objects":[{"type":"textbox","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":40,"top":350,"width":200,"height":20.97,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":"ADDRESScanvasPage2","fontSize":16,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.16,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"center","textBackgroundColor":"","styles":{},"minWidth":20}],"background":""}"}
```

Comment: That's some horribly formatted json

Comment: Post valid json... nobody can read that and it has syntax errors in it making it difficult to pretty format it! In adddition you haven't provided any attempts to resolve this. Show us what you tried. People aren't here to do your work for you

Comment: Even after the edit, it's still invalid JSON! And you don't need count to loop thru them.

Comment: This is not a JSON array as an array starts with [.
You have an object with two properties: canvas0 and canvas1, each of them has the property "objects" that is an array.
What you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, your JSON is invalid. The same valid JSON in minimal would look like the following.

```
var json = {
    "canvas0": {
        "objects": [
            {
                "type": "textbox",
                "originX": "left"
            }
        ],
        "background": "#000"
    },
    "canvas1": {
        "objects": [
            {
                "type": "select",
                "originX": "right"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

To be able to iterate thru, you don't need the count of top level keys. And moreover, a JSON object doesn't have the length property. All you need to do is, use `for...in` loops and display the key/values accordingly. Here is an example of how you can do it. Bear in mind that *this only works with your specific case* as the loop needs changing as and when the JSON levels change.

```
alert ( "Length of top level keys: " + Object.keys(json).length );

for (var key in json) {

    var canvas = json[key];
    for (var key2 in canvas) {

        if (canvas[key2] instanceof Array) {
            var object = canvas[key2][0];
            for (var key3 in object) {
                alert (key3 + ": " + object[key3]);
            }
        } else {
            alert (key2 + ": " + canvas[key2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngkLf6x8/) with the complete code.